# What does the Notification “badge” on MacOS System Preferences icon really mean?

Tags: macos, security

If you have recently upgraded your MacOS laptop/desktop to 10.12.14, you will have noticed that now the System Preferences icon in the doc shows a mysterious “notification badge”:

[image: System Preferences dock icon]

Just opening System Preferences shows absolutely no clue as to where the notification is coming from, nor what to do about it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out that Apple really wants you to take security seriously (you should!) and is promoting the use of Two-Factor Authentication (2FA) for iCloud accounts.

If you click on the iCloud icon, you will be presented with the message which was the notification source:

[image: iCloud Preferences]

If you hit the “Continue” button you will be presented with the opportunity of enabling 2FA, learning more (please do this at least), or leaving it off for now.

Comment: Originally posted on http://codetrips.com

Comment: I have to say that was anything but intuitive. I checked the System Preferences and of course there is nothing in the main window to give you any clues. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On MAC Os Sierra I had the same notification, this post at least sent me to the right place, but i found that it was iCloud needing me to sign in again as some services ? required this. See screenshot. I can only think it was because i re-enabled and old iPhone using my same apple ID. [Screenshot of iCloud requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ7jM.png)

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want the "red dot of shame" create an alias for system preferences, remove system preferences from the dock and then add the alias in its place